# getting Invalid semver string: "undefined"

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-cdk

Going through a Udemy tutorial on AWS CDK and Typescript.  The video is about two years old and the instructor had just started using the new 2.0.0 release of the CDK. So, that may be part of my problem. I'm getting the below error when I run CDK synth --verbose

```
    Invalid semver string: "undefined"
[21:30:22] Error: Invalid semver string: "undefined"
    at parseVersion (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:31:8255000)
    at Function.validate (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:31:8255125)
    at Function.loadManifest (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:32:594)
    at Function.loadAssemblyManifest (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:31:8254222)
    at new CloudAssembly (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:32:14396)
    at createAssembly (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:329:15973)
    at execProgram (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:329:15438)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object.CloudExecutable.synthesizer (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:385:50431)
    at async CloudExecutable.doSynthesize (C:\Users\DREWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:329:7689)
```

Didn't know I needed a manifest.json file until I got the error beforehand that it wasn't found when I ran "cdk synth". No idea what should go in it, so I downloaded a sample from AWS. Here are the contents

```
{
    "default": {
      "version": "v0.0.1",
      "telemetry": {
        "deploy": true,
        "env": {
          "telemetryTopic": "smartproduct/telemetry"
        }
      },
      "events": {
        "deploy": true,
        "env": {
          "eventTopic": "smartproduct/event"
        }
      },
      "jitr": {
        "deploy": true
      },
      "api": {
        "deploy": true
      },
      "ownerapp": {
        "deploy": true
        }
      }
    }
```

Here are the versions:
Node: v14.17.6

NPM: 6.14.15

aws-cdk: 2.63.2

Couldn't find any help in Stack Overflow, github or AWS regarding this particular error and scenario.  Is there a way to run cdk synth without requiring a manifest.json?

Comment: The CDK produces a `manifest.json` build artefact in the `cdk.out` directory.  In 99.9999% of cases you should never have to think about it or interact with it, much less write to it.  Hard to say what your root problem is.  Consider getting started wtih AWS's https://cdkworkshop.com.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev! I ended up searching instead on missing manifest.json, and found https://gitter.im/awslabs/aws-cdk?at=5de02eb032df1245cbaabfc7, from which I started over and ran "cdk init --language typescript" instead of "npm i -D aws-cdk aws-cdk-lib constructs ts-node typescript". That resolved the issue.